# Letters labeled 1 ... 2n are placed into envelopes labeled 1 ... 2n

Tags: probability

The numbers $1,\ldots, 2n$ are written on $2n$ letters. The numbers $1,\ldots, 2n$ are also written on $2n$ envelopes. The letters are placed at random into the envelopes, and for each envelope-letter combination the number written on the letter is added to the number written on the envelope. This gives $2n$ sums.

Find:

a.) The probability that every sum is even.

Result: $1 \over \binom {2n}{n}$

b.) The probability that exactly two of the sums is even.

Result: $n^2 \over \binom {2n}{n}$

I don't see how this is? Can anyone help? Classic probability.

Comment: Can you work out the details in some small cases, say, $n=1$, $n=2$, and maybe see from there what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

a) Suppose that you are only concerned with which $n$ envelopes get paired with an even numbered letter. This can be done in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways if we ignore the permutation of the letters they are paired with. But these have to be exactly all the even numbered envelopes, and that combination can only be chosen in one way, ignoring again the permutation of the letters they are paired with.

b) By the same construction as before, there is only one way out of $\binom{2n}{n}$ to have NO even sums. From such a situation, we can get to any situation with exactly two even sums by swapping an even and an odd envelope. This can be done in $n^2$ ways, again ignoring the permutation of the letters.